# Combine results from two independent queries

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, join

I'm fairly new to Postgres and need to fetch two separate data :
1) values of avg, min, max of various records/resuts of table T1
2) column values of the 'last' record of the table T1  based on the most recent timestamp

The problem is I cannot run these queries separately as it will cause performance issues. (the data in this table can be in tens of thousands or records and combining them into a result object, even more complex).

Is it possible to combine the results of these two data side by side into one monster of a query that will return the desired output?

Appreciate your help.

Updated with queries:

1st query :

```
select
    rtp.id, rtp.received_timestamp,
    rtp.agent_time, rtp.sourceip, rtp.destip, rtp.sourcedscp,
    sum(rtp.numduplicate) as dups, avg(rtp.numduplicate) as avgdups,
    min(rtp.numduplicate) as mindups, max(rtp.numduplicate) as maxdups
from rtp_test_result rtp
where
    rtp.received_timestamp between 1274723208 and 1475642299
group by rtp.sourceip, rtp.destip, rtp.sourcedscp
order by rtp.sourceip, rtp.destip, rtp.sourcedscp
```

2nd query:

```
select id, received_timestamp, numooo
from rtp_test_result 
where received_timestamp = (select max(received_timestamp) mrt from rtp_test_result)
group by id,received_timestamp, numooo 
order by id desc limit 1
```

Comment: "The problem is I cannot run these queries separately as it will cause performance issues." Details? Have you checked - `explain analyze`? What makes you think that combining them into one query will help? Please show your current queries, explain analyze output, and the PostgreSQL version.

Comment: Updated the question with the queries. Not sure how to capture the explain analyze data. I'm running postgresql 1.8 on RHEL 6.

Comment: You need to group by different things with different ordering rules and need different column outputs. I struggle to see how these two can be combined usefully. Run them with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and post the results. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like

```
with cte as (
    select
        val,
        last_value(val) over(order by ts asc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as lst_value
    from T1
)
select
    avg(val) as avg_value,
    min(val) as min_value,
    max(val) as max_value,
    max(lst_value) as lst_value
from cte
```

or

```
select
    avg(val) as avg_value,
    min(val) as min_value,
    max(val) as max_value,
    (select val from T1 order by ts desc limit 1) as lst_value
from T1
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a9f27/21)

Comment: tried the first part of your answer and it seems to work. My query needs to fetch a lot more records (about 25-30). Will construct the final query and then mark as resolved. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Combining a few more aggregates works well but as soon as I add some non-aggregate columns like a ref-id or type the query requires grouping by these. Trying to figure out if I can get rid of that.